# Adding lines to scatter plot from multiple columns of two Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, scatter-plot

I am creating a scatter plot from multiple columns of two pandas DataFrames, and would like to join the markers with lines. Below is some example code.

Creating two DataFrames:

```
inYs= pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(low=0.3, high=0.450, size=(100)))
inYs[1]= np.random.uniform(low=0.1, high=0.2, size=(100))
inYs[2]= np.random.uniform(low=0.03, high=0.05, size=(100))
inYs[3]= np.random.uniform(low=0, high=0.02, size=(100))
inYs=inYs.T

inXs=pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(low=0.3, high=0.0, size=(100)))
inXs[1]=np.random.uniform(low=5.0, high=3.5, size=(100))
inXs[2]=np.random.uniform(low=7.5, high=5.0, size=(100))
inXs[3]=np.random.uniform(low=10, high=9, size=(100))
inXs=inXs.T
```

Creating scatterplots by iterating through columns of the two DataFrames:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17, 10))
fig.clf()
ax1 = plt.axes()

for i in np.arange(1, 100):
    for (x,y)in zip(inXs[i],inYs[i]):
        ax1.plot(x, y,"-p", color='grey')
```

This creates a [scatter plot of multiple columns from two dataframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiiZY.png)
, but the markers are not joined despite using linestyle "-p" (I have tried a few different linestyles).

I would be grateful for ideas on how to join the markers of the scatter plot when iterating through the columns. Or is there a way to create a multiple line plots by iterating through sets of x-values and y-values in another way?

I have been trying to find a solution for this on SO for hours but still cannot work out what I am doing wrong here. This is the first time I have given up and asked a question, so forgive me if this is obvious to more experienced coders!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that your (x, y)-pairs you plot are single points. Connections between markers are plotted if you plot lists of y against lists of x values. Which markers should be connected to which others? These should be packed into the mentioned lists.

Just to give an example, how y-list against x-list leads to plotted lines; of course I doubt that this is the plot you wanted to create...

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17, 10))
fig.clf()
ax1 = plt.axes()

for i in np.arange(1, 100):
    for (x,y)in zip(inXs[i],inYs[i]):
        ax1.plot(inXs[i], inYs[i], 'o-')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful, it seems that I don't need this line at all: "for (x,y)in zip(inXs[i],inYs[i])", which makes sense in retrospect, as I wanted to plot the columns not the individual points. Thanks again!